# PowerShell "DO...Until" Try and Catch for valid data not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell to check if a user-provided position number exists. I want to loop this until the user provides a valid position. I am fairly new to PowerShell and I don't understand why it's not working...

```
#Start Store and Check Budget Position Number User Template#
Clear-Host

Do{
Try{
  # Find the user template
  $budgetpositionnumber = Read-Host " 
    What budget position number is the user filling? 
" 
Write-Host "
You entered budget position number: $budgetpositionnumber
" 
  # Find the position on Your.Domain
  Get-ADuser $budgetpositionnumber
  
}
Catch{
  Write-Host ("Failed to find position number " + $budgetpositionnumber) -ForegroundColor Red -ErrorAction Stop
}
} Until ($budgetpositionnumber -ne $Null)
#End Store and Check Budget Position Number Template#
```

Even if I enter invalid data, it still continues with the rest of the script. I want it to stop or loop until its' a vaild position number.

##Edited for clarity

Comment: If I read correctly, you're looking for a security group but using `Get-ADuser` instead of `Get-ADGroup`. Can you clarify on this?

Comment: try/catch only works with _terminating_ errors. You can force a non-terminating error to become a terminating error for a given command by adding `-ErrorAction Stop`. I commend to your attention [Microsoft Docs on `try`/`catch`/`finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Sorry, I should clean up my post. I intended to use Get-ADuser. Not Get-ADGroup. I am checking for a user name to copy as a template not an SG.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, believe the AD cmdlets are all bugged and all throw terminating errors by default. Unless you meant the `Write-Host`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - The way the question is phrased, the implication is that the `Get-ADUser` is throwing a _nonterminating_ error, which won't get caught by `try`/`catch`. However, the real problem here, on re-inspection, is the `until` clause, which Santiago Squarzon caught.

Answer (score 2):

> *"Even if I enter invalid data, it still continues with the rest of the script"*

The [`do` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do?view=powershell-7.2) always ends because it's `until` condition always evaluates to `$true` no matter what the input is, this is because **any string, even if [`Empty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty?view=net-7.0), is not equal to `$null`**.

---

The condition:

```bash
Until ($budgetpositionnumber -ne $Null)
```

Should be testing if [`Get-ADuser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps) found any object instead of testing if there was an input provided in [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.2).

---

As for how you can approach the code:

```
do {
    $userinput = Read-Host "something here..."
    Write-Host "You entered budget position number: $userinput"
    try {
        $found = Get-ADuser $userinput
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "No account with Name '$userinput' exists..."
    }
} until ($found)
```